# jquery not taking effect immeditaly

Tags: jquery

When I load up my tumblr blog at http://ginnypig.tumblr.com you will notice there's a short pause before the style kicks in. I find this ugly and was wondering what can be done. If you miss it, just refresh and you'll see what I mean.

I've established the problem is with the following jquery:

```
{block:Description}
        <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {block:IndexPage}
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/Ebfm2v4gy/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/u2vm2hxv6/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
    {/block:IndexPage}
```

But I don't know what I need to do to stop this slight stutter in the page loading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is not about animation speed, then you have to reduce the functions between the click and actual firing of the event and try to use as little custom script as possible. You could try to link the click and fire event by id instead of class if you have not done that yet. Else try adding async (load scripts parallel in background)

Comment: It's actually not doing it now, but I guess that's because of my cache?? Thank you very much for the quick response, but I should have added in my OP, that I am a complete and utter noob, and none of what you said makes the slightest bit of sense.

Comment: Try adding async to all included scripts like so <script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Okay, Nitin, done that. Thank you. There does still seem to be a slight pause, but what I see before the style kicks in is slightly easier on the eye than before. Thing is, I'm not sure if it's because the site is cached. Does it appear to load faster for you now?

Comment: Scrap that, something definately wrong now. If I open the page in a new tab, it doesn't load properly until I refresh the page.

Comment: If you do not need the last two scripts, you could comment them out. The problem could be with the scroller. Else try moving these files to the bottom of the html document just before the closing body tag </body>

Comment: Thanks again, @Nitin. I've had enough for tonight, but will try this tomorrow and report back with my findings.

Comment: @Nitin. Both these solutions (commenting out last two scripts or moving the scripts to just before the closing body tag) causes everything but the sidebar to disappear. I suppose all I can ask now is for you to tell me if the page loads smoothly for you. It does for me, but I presume that's down to caching.

Comment: I do not see a lag but scrolling i a little slow, presumably because of the scroller script

Comment: @Nitin Thank you for checking. Not sure what you mean by scrolling. On my monitor there is not yet enough content to trigger the need for page scrolling. What devise are you using please?

Comment: iphone 5s, dont worry too much about it though, almost all major sites have this. The scroller scripts are continuously checking if the document was scrolled which can reduce the reaction time during scrolling of the page. (Any js file that is not loaded asynchronously -- async -- can delay the loading of the page, especially if the js files are large).

Comment: Okay, @Nitin. Thanks very much for your continued help - much appreciated! We'll call this one closed.